# Was the Sandy Hook massacre an elaborate hoax? (and other conspiracies)

Tags: government, weapons

I have heard a number of people talking about some serious and seemingly implausible allegations that the Sandy Hook shooting was an elaborate hoax.

Most of the sources for these claims I have found compiled on Wikipedia which I will post for the time being:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandy_Hook_Elementary_School_shooting_conspiracy_theories

Here are some of the claims below:

- The FBI reported that no murders occurred at Sandy Hook [Source](http://www.infowars.com/fbi-says-no-one-killed-at-sandy-hook/)
- Video taken of the father of one of the victims shown smiling only a day after the event [Source](http://www.neonnettle.com/features/333-fbi-evidence-shows-sandy-hook-shooting-could-have-been-elaborate-hoax)

  - A number of tweets about the incident have timestamps that occurred after the event occurred [Source](http://jenniferlake.wordpress.com/?s=sandy+hook+tweets)
  - The event was a joint government-media operation to garner support for an assault weapons ban. [Source](http://beforeitsnews.com/conspiracy-theories/2013/01/evidence-sandy-hook-school-shooting-staged-by-factions-of-us-government-and-mainstream-media-3-2447784.html)

There are many other claims I have heard verbally spoken that I have yet to find sources on...

- The children are all still alive and have been spotted at public events, baseball games and even photos showing one of the children at the white house after the event
- Adam Lanza is not and never has been a real person, that his birth and death certificate are unavailable and evidence suggests all known photos of him were computer generated.
- Some memorial sites and fund-raising sites for the victims appeared or were registered days before the shooting event occurred.

I am not even going to give credence to some of the ridiculous anti-semitic theories that are floating around this.  The only thing I can say is that if this were some elaborate plot pulled off by the Obama administration to ban assault weapons then it failed miserably.

Is there hard evidence to dispel some of these absurd theories?

Comment: It is too hard to address all of the claims in one answer, so this should be broken into separte questions. Snopes has a whole article on the "No Murders reported" claim - so that is one question by itself. Lanza never existed is another, etc.